# Python3 ConnectionRefusedError selenium.webdriver.Remote on Ubuntu Server

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
cap = {'browserName': 'chrome'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url, desired_capabilities=cap)
```

I try this on Ubuntu Server, but i have error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 156, in _new_conn
conn = connection.create_connection(

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
raise err

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection

 sock.connect(sa)

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
self.send(msg)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
self.connect()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 184, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
raise NewConnectionError(

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6377a9f8e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test.py", line 89, in <module>
test_some.testMethod()

File "test.py", line 21, in testMethod
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=selenium_url, desired_capabilities=caps)

File "/home/vl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File "/home/vl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

File "/home/vl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

File "/home/vl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

File "/home/vl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 79, in request
return self.request_encode_body(

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)

 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 330, in urlopen
response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
return self.urlopen(

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
return self.urlopen(

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 747, in urlopen
return self.urlopen(

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment

raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6377a9f8e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

i have Chrome on Ubuntu Server

further idea is to open the link, after a while exit the window / browser

is it possible to run it successfully?

or are there other libraries to solve this problem?

I do not know what else to write so that I can post this question here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused` is showing that your script is unable to access the remote Selenium server.

In order to use a remote web driver, [selenium server](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) should be running on that remote Ubuntu server, and `chrome driver` executable file should be available in the `$PATH`. You can read further about it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver)

So, make sure:

- You have downloaded the `chrome driver` from the official [site](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and placed it in the `$PATH`
- You have downloaded the `Selenium server` from the official [site](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) and have it running on the remote Ubuntu server. You can simply start the Selenium server like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.XXX.XX.jar
```

Selenium server by default binds to all available network interfaces with a default base URL `wd/hub` as you have shown in the code snippet:

```py
url = "http://[HOST]:4444/wd/hub"
```

If you are going to use your script on the same server where the Selenium server is running, `localhost` should be alright. But if you are going to use it from a remote location you need to provide the correct IP/domain of the Selenium server.

I would suggest If you intend to use your script locally on a Linux server machine (non-GUI environment), you can utilize the headless mode of Chrome/Firefox to achieve the same thing. You can use the `headless` option like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com.pk')
print(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! Although there were a few more errors in the process, I've already found answers to them.